# cunnilingus vs cunnilinctus

Tags: word-comparison

I'm interested in the morphology of these two words. How are they structured and does their structure affect their meaning at all?

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I've had to remind people that there is no letter `t` after either `n` in the first syllable. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

***Cunnilingus*** is an actual classical Latin word, used several times by Martial and once in the Priapea. It is formed from *cunnus* (the vulva, but it is an obscene word), and the verb *lingere* (to lick), and it means "someone who licks the vulva," or if you want a translation that is more idiomatic English and mirrors the level of speech, a "pussy licker." While interpreted by lexicographers as a masculine noun, it could in theory also be an adjective ("licking the vulva").

The way it is formed is that a second-declension masculine noun was formed from the present stem of the verb. The noun got Latin's usual 'i' binding vowel, that should not be interpreted as a normal noun form. This method of forming words referring to a person or thing doing something -- the result being a first/second-declension adjective or a first or second declension noun -- is not so unusual, compare for example:

- *lucifugus, -a, -um* (*lux* + *fugere*): light-shunning
- *lucifuga, -ae, m*: a light-shunner, someone who thrives at night
- *lucipetus, -a, -um* (*lux* + *petere*): light-seeking
- *aquifuga, -ae, c* (*aqua* + *fugere*): someone who fears water, a sufferer of hydrophobia
- *lucifer, -a, -um* (*lux* + *ferre*): light-bringing; as a noun *Lucifer*: the morning star, i.e., the planet Venus

It seems to me there is a tendency that these words describe a person or thing performing the action habitually or characteristically -- not necessarily right at this moment. Otherwise we would not need a compositum, we would use the present participle. Many of these words are rare or hapax legomena (words that are attested only once in the known literature/inscriptions).

Note: This is the Latin meaning; it is not the meaning of the word when used in English. When "cunnilingus" is used in English, it is refers to the sexual practice of licking the vulva. It is also not obscene, but rather a medical/scientific term. This usage is incorrect from a Latin point of view, but well established and supported by the dictionaries (in fact, I'd say it is the only meaning understood by most English speakers.)

***Cunnilinctus*** is a word I did not know before I came across this question. It is unknown to all Latin dictionaries I consulted. It is very likely completely unattested in all periods of Latin.

What it is supposed to be is not hard to guess: a fourth-declension masculine noun formed from the supine stem of the verb *lingere* (i.e., *linctum*), and referring to the act of licking a vulva, not the actor. That is at least my guess, because that is a very common way Latin forms verbal nouns, and many well-known words are of this kind, e.g. *status* (from *stare*), *exitus* (from *exire*), *situs* (from *sinere*), etc.

Why this word was created, and by whom, I do not know, but I did notice on Google Books that it exists not only in English, but also in German, and that it is, among others, used in texts dealing with Roman sexual mores and quoting Latin literature, i.e., by authors who should know what they're doing. I assume the reason for creating this word was to avoid using *cunnilingus* incorrectly, which some authors, however established it may be, might feel they should avoid. This makes particular sense in works dealing with Latin literature and inscriptions.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: Cunnilinctus was invented in modern times, probably by people who wanted to express the modern meaning of cunnilingus but objected to using a latin word in a way that doesn't match its latin grammar?

Comment: @Nobody that is a good summary, yes.

Comment: Should we understand that there was no word at all in Latin for the act of pussy-licking, or was there some word formed in a totally different way ?

Comment: @Evargalo No, to my knowledge there is no dedicated word. See also [Wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_obscenity) on Latin obscenity. You can of course simply say *cunnum lingere*, as e.g. Martial does in Ep. 7,67: *Di mentem tibi dent tuam, Philaeni, cunnum lingere quae putas virile* (freely: "May the gods give you some sense, Philaenis, if you think licking pussy is manly"). The same epigram also offers the nigh untranslatable expression *medias puellas vorare* for the same act...